# Pose Mode and Bone problem [Blender 2.83]

Tags: bones, pose-mode

So I have scoured Blender Stack Exchange trying to find an answer on why my bones are refusing to change to a selectable state inside pose mode. [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpGKM.jpg)

I haven't found anything that fixes my issue.
I am working with separate objects, but I went to a fresh file, and I had separate objects on separate bones attached to the same armature(where each bone is parented to one object), just like in my file, and it worked just fine.

Things I've tried:

1. Deselecting *In Front*
2. Appending the Armature to a fresh file
3. Trying the *Circle Select*(having difficulties) v2.8 only?
4. Made a new armature, selected both it, and another bone and hitting *Ctrl+j*
5. *Disable Selection* in the Outlier isn't the problem
6. Clearing parents and reparenting everything

https://blend-exchange.com/b/LvJ8Bkw4

Comment: I think the object did not assigned with weight painting to the bone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one bone in your active armature that can be selected. See the green bone icon next to the green armature icon in Outliner. Looks like you have created a separate armature for each bone. Select all armatures in Objectmode and CTRL + J (join).

Comment: This is probably the answer, however everytime I try to do this, the program crashes...

Comment: Apparently if you don't have any bones selected as 'active' when you join them, the program crashes.

I was joining all the bones bones together and I deselected an object I accidently selected. leaving nothing on a 'active' highlighted selection. At least that's what I think was happening.